Six Darshanas and their means of reason and authenticity of Dharmasutra, Dharmashastras and Nitishastra
I am looking out how mainly the 6 Darshanas, but especially Advaita viewed Dharmasutra, Dharmashastras, and Nitishastra and how to interpret them in the constant change of the world. Traditional sources only are allowed no Neo-Vedantin stuff.
